# Laravel's validation failed for boolean value sended by Postman

Tags: php, laravel, postman, lumen

In my Lumen API I check a request body using the `Validator` facade. One of the attribute of the request called `private` has to be of type `boolean`. So I check my request like that:

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'private' => 'required|boolean',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // invalid request body...
};
```

So I make my request in Postman using the `x-www-form-urlencoded` 'format':

[image]

But then I get an error message as response:

```js
{
    "private": [
        "The private field must be true or false."
    ]
}
```

But it work as expected if I replace `true` by `1` in Postman

Have I miss something in my Postman configuration?

Comment: May be you have to send data from raw

Comment: Postman is sending the `string` `'true'` and not the `boolean` `true`, so you have to keep using `1` or `0` to make it work

Comment: Ok for Postman but at the end it will be really painfull to send it via `json`

Answer (score 1):

Check [Laravel rule in](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-in), you can use **"any_field" => "string|in:true,false"**, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel validation boolean rule](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-boolean) check if the data is `true, false, 1, 0, "1", and "0".` I think when you send using postman the value `true` is sended like a string `'true'`

Comment: Really curious that Laravel don't handle them as string too since a http request cast everythong has a string

Comment: Yes, it is curious. In this post they are talking about the subject in case you are interested. [Boolean validation does not accept "true" and "false", but accepts "1", "0"](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/514)

Comment: Yeah I also read this issue and I will also finally use the `in:true,false` validation test and then cast it as a boolean

Answer (score 0):

If any is out here looking for an answer: Just use

> 'private'=> 'required|boolean',

Atleast it works in **laravel 8** as of April 2022

Docs: The field under validation must be able to be cast as a boolean. Accepted input are true, false, 1, 0, "1", and "0".

Answer (score 0):

Same thing with 'in query' boolean parameters. The value is coming as a string so I convert it before validation using the function `prepareForValidation()` in my requests:

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'private' => filter_var($this->get('private'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
    ]);
}
```